# Unity - Tinting mesh UVs

Tags: unity-game-engine, mesh

I followed the lovely tutorial by Sebastian Lague here [Link to tutorial](https://learn.unity.com/project/procedural-cave-generation-tutorial). I applied it to my own scenario where I want to generate landmass, and ended up with a cool result:

[image]

As you can see in the image there is a grid, this is simply a texture that is repeated (tiled) x amount of times and applied to the generated mesh. The code for that looks like this:

```
Vector2[] uvs = new Vector2[vertices.Count];
        for (int i = 0; i < vertices.Count; i++)
        {
            float percentX = Mathf.InverseLerp(-map.GetLength(0) / 2 * squareSize, map.GetLength(0) / 2 * squareSize, vertices[i].x) * tileAmount;
            float percentY = Mathf.InverseLerp(-map.GetLength(0) / 2 * squareSize, map.GetLength(0) / 2 * squareSize, vertices[i].z) * tileAmount;
            uvs[i] = new Vector2(percentX, percentY);
        }
        mesh.uv = uvs;
```

I am wondering, if there is any way to tint each tile a different shade during this process, either in this script or using a shader.

Comment: One extra thing - when you start affecting the mesh with more complex lights, you might start noticing it being lit weirdly/incorrectly. That's because your mesh is (probably) missing Mesh.normals, so you might want to generate those too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Vertex colors](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mesh-colors.html)

They will be automatically interpolated for smooth gradients. If you don't want that, you'll have to build the mesh so that each square has separate vertices, not shared with the neighboring squares.